# How to redirect the output of `apt-file update` into a file?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, updates

I have a zsh function which updates my system (`.deb` packages, `pip` packages, texlive packages, ...).

It looks like this:

```
up() {
  emulate -LR zsh
  [[ -d "${HOME}/log" ]] || mkdir "${HOME}/log"
  LOGFILE="${HOME}/log/update_system.log"
  __update_system 2>&1 | tee -a "${LOGFILE}"
}
```

The last line calls the `__update_system` function and pipes its output to `tee`, which in turn should display the output on the terminal, and append it to a file, so that I can review it later if something went wrong.

One of the commands executed by `__update_system` is:

```
$ apt-file update
```

It seems to be executed, but its output is not logged in the file.
All the other commands (including `aptitude update`) are logged.

I tried to understand by executing this command in a shell:

```
$ apt-file update >/tmp/log
```

Again, `apt-file update` seems to be executed, but the output is not logged as `/tmp/log` is empty.

I thought that maybe the output is sent on the standard error, so I tried:

```
$ apt-file update >/tmp/log 2>&1
```

But I got the same result, an empty file.

I tried in bash, which also gave me an empty file.

---

Here are some details about my system:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-135-generic #161-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 27 10:45:01 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

About zsh:

```
$ zsh --version
zsh 5.5.1-dev-0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

About bash:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.0(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
```

About `apt-file`:

```
$ aptitude show apt-file
Package: apt-file
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Version: 2.5.5ubuntu1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/admin
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Uncompressed Size: 92,2 k
Depends: perl, curl, libconfig-file-perl, libapt-pkg-perl, liblist-moreutils-perl, libregexp-assemble-perl,
         libfile-temp-perl
Suggests: openssh-client, sudo
Description: search for files within Debian packages (command-line interface)
 apt-file is a command line tool for searching files contained in packages for the APT packaging system. You can search
 in which package a file is included or list the contents of a package without installing or fetching it.
```

---

How to redirect the output of `apt-file update` into a file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `apt-file` is a perl script.
- It uses [diffindex-download](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/diffindex-download.1.html). That is another perl script.
- That one writes to `/dev/tty` and not to `stdout` (the difference is explained on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4668579/2920227))
- Soooo... this will log the output to `logfile.log`

  ```
  script -c "apt-file update" logfile.log
  ```